# How to open Emacs 24.5 maximized from terminal in OSX?

Tags: osx

So far I have only used Emacs on Ubuntu. So it was time for a change, and on my new MacBook Pro, I installed Emacs 24.5 from http://emacsformacosx.com/

Now, when I go to the terminal window and type

```
$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -mm
```

Emacs does not open maximized. What am I missing here? (I have not created any Emacs init file yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the `-mm -fs -fh -fw` flags do not work with OS X because they require X11 to work. I've tried them in Linux and they work fine there. However the `-g` flag does work. For a 1920x1200 display you can pass a geometry of `271x82` and you'll get a maximised frame.

I prefer to use code to set this up, I use the following snippet to maximise emacs when started, the benefit is that no matter the display geometry I always get emacs to display as expected.

```
(let ((px (display-pixel-width))
  (py (display-pixel-height))
  (fx (frame-char-width))
  (fy (frame-char-height))
  tx ty)
(setq tx (- (/ px fx) 7))
(setq ty (- (/ py fy) 4))
(setq initial-frame-alist '((top . 2) (left . 2)))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'width tx))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'height ty)))
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, maybe better ways, but this is enough for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to my init file works:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```